# check the validity of a statement in specific rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, lapply

I have a data frame (`nxm`) in *R*, namely `A`, like this

```
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50 * 10, mean = 0, sd = 1), 50, 10))
colnames(A) <-
  c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")
```

For every fifth row in the data (`A[1, ], A[6, ], A[11, ], A[16, ],...,A[46, ]`), I want see if the column `X1` contains the greatest value across all of the columns starting with `"X"`for that row. In the end, I would like to have a single number reflecting the percentage of these rows for which column `X1` contains the largest value across the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
sA <- A[seq.int(1, nrow(A), by = 5), ]  ## keep rows 1, 6, 11, ...
logi <- rowSums(sA$X1 > sA[-1]) == (ncol(A) - 1)  ## X1 > other columns
mean(logi)  ## the percentage of the above event
```

> In the case where negative values appear, it does not seem to work. I produced a row with X1= -3.12, X2= -3.44, X3=-3.71, X4=-4.34, .... I know X1 is the highest but appears as FALSE in `logi`. Why is that?

The row you presented in [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0tbB.png) is on the 2nd row. You want to skip the 2nd row, don't you? `logi` is computed on row 1, 6, 11, .... In the end, `logi` has 10 not 50 logical values. So [the 2nd FALSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykYWT.png) is not for row 2, but for row 6.

*(I added link to the screenshots, because OP removed them in a later edit.)*

> Now, seems to work perfectly! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We can just extract every fifth row with `filter()`, turn it into long data structure with `pivot_longer()`, then pull out variables with the maximum per row with `group_by()` and `slice_max()` then create indicators for the variable value.

## Example data

You'll need to `set.seed` to create reproducible data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)

A <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50 * 10, mean = 0, sd = 1), 50, 10))
colnames(A) <-
  c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")
```

## Get desired percentages

```r
# Add row id and only keep 5th rows
A5 <- A %>%
  mutate(row_id = 1:nrow(A)) %>%
  filter(row_number() %% 6 == 0 |
           row_number() == 1)

# Pivot so each variable is its own row
A5_long <- A5 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("X"),
               names_to = "variable",
               values_to = "values")

# Get maximum value for each row then
# check if the variable is X1 and add indicator
results <- A5_long %>%
  group_by(row_id) %>%
  slice_max(values) %>%
  mutate(max_is_X1 = ifelse(variable == "X1", 1, 0))

print(results)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   row_id [9]
#>   row_id variable values max_is_X1
#>    <int> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1      1 X5        2.20          0
#> 2      6 X1        1.72          1
#> 3     12 X7        0.757         0
#> 4     18 X10       1.72          0
#> 5     24 X4        2.13          0
#> 6     30 X1        1.25          1
#> 7     36 X8        1.38          0
#> 8     42 X10       1.40          0
#> 9     48 X2        1.53          0

# Get percentage
AR <- paste0(round(mean(results$max_is_X1) * 100, 0), "%")

print(AR)
#> [1] "22%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not quite correct, I want to chech row_id 1,6,11, etc. So basically can i make it start from the 1st row and then extract every fifth row (6,11,...)?

Comment: You already accepted an answer, which indicates that you do not need additional answers/help. I've updated it, however, to those rows. All you need to do is to manipulate the rows it filters on to change the specific rows. It will do the same thing on each row regardless of the rows passed, so it's highly flexible. The `filter()` part basically says "get any row whose row number is a multiple of 6 OR whose row number is 1". The %% is called a modulo operator I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we could do it:

1. Create an id column with rownumber (later important to get the desired rows
2. Here we filter out row 6, 11, 16, etc... as desired. By using the modulo operator %% we simply check if the row number is divisible by 5 and then add 1
3. `mutate(across(-c(X1, id), ~. < X1, 1, 0)*1) %>%` this looks complicated but is not: here we mutate across all columns but X1, and id then within an anonymous function (~) we check if all (.) e.g. columns X2:X10 are smaller X1, if so 1 else 0. The *1 makes 0 1 out of FALSE and TRUE
4. Now we check if the rowsums X2:X10 are equal to 9 (because 9 rows, if all are 1 eg. TRUE then it should be 9) if yes 1 else 0.
5. save to dataframe B
6. Next we use df A, after adding an id column we join with df B
7. caluclate the AR wtih sum of check column divided by rows in df A *100
8. slice 1 to pull only one AR

```
library(dplyr)

B <- A %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(row_number()%%5==0+1) %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(X1, id), ~. < X1, 1, 0)*1) %>%
  mutate(x  = rowSums(. [2:10])) %>% 
  mutate(check = ifelse(x==9, 1, 0)) %>% 
  select(id, check) 

A %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(B, by="id") %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  mutate(AR = paste0(sum(check, na.rm = TRUE)/nrow(B)*100, "%")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pull(AR)
```